# Unable to “run as different user” in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am not able to "run as different user" in my windows 7 (domain login) machine.

For example if i'm trying to start iexplore (run as diff user) It returns the error :

"The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: What's the _exact_ command you're typing in?

Comment: Shift+right click on internet explorer and "run as different user" then i'm entering username and password but it says "the system cannot find the file specified"